# apt-get: command not found in mysql docker CLI

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, shell

as a first... yes...yes I know there are 1000 questions and solutions to this. But unfortunately none of them helps me.

Let's get to the problem:

I have a Docker container running on which MySQL is configured. Now I would like to change the bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0. Unfortunately I can't open my.cnf because I don't have nano, vim installed. With apk, yum, vim, apt-get and so on I get that:

```
apt-get: command not found
apk: command not found
...
```

Could someone of you maybe help me out with my little problem?
best thanks and greetings

Comment: The standard [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has this configured correctly.  Changing a config file inside a running container usually isn't effective: you'd have to restart the main container process, and the best way to do that is to recreate the container, which loses your manual edit.  Do you have a custom image?  Can you set up its configuration correctly in the Dockerfile?

Comment: hmm ok sounds good. I mean i have also changed things in my nginx container. and there the apt-get command works fine. 
And its not a custom image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default for MySQL docker image has been changed to Oracle based Linux distribution. In this distribution, the default package manager is `yum`. If for whatever reason you still want to use `apt`, pull Debian image explicitly. Something like `mysql:8-debian`.

See this [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/877) for more detail.

Comment: Finally the real solution! Thanks that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `docker cp` to copy the file out of the container, edit it, and then `docker cp` it back in again. This may be fine if you need to do this for troubleshooting, but you probably want to look at fixing this in your deployment process. You should be able to destroy and re-create the docker container without having to manually fix configurations. This should be handled in your Dockerfile, or perhaps copying the correct configuration file in in your docker compose file.

Comment: So you mean i should simple copy the my.cnf file out of the container change it and put it back into the container.

Comment: `docker cp`ing the existing file out make might sense, but you should use something like a `docker run -v` bind mount to inject the modified file into the container at startup time.  You generally should not edit files inside running containers or copy modified files into them.  Use debugging tools like `docker cp` or `docker exec` sparingly and recognize that they're not generally part of reproducible workflows.

Comment: yes, but as David mentions, the correct configuration should be in the docker at startup time. I was only suggesting that it's possible to do on-the-fly edits using `docker cp` , if you need to do it for troubleshooting purposes. But really, your docker should come up in the desired state so that you can easily destroy and re-create.